# How to calculate the points of the triangles making up an Octahedron?

Tags: vector-spaces, education, 3d, coordinate-systems, geometry

Ok guys, I'm not a great mathematician but will try to work this as accurately as I can.  I hope someone can help me.

I am drawing some 3D objects and I am having trouble drawing an Octahedron. I need to dynamically calculate all points of each triangle in the Octahedron based on two known factors, the topmost XYZ point of the shape and the bottommost XYZ point of the shape.

[image: Octahedron]

What I am looking is to create Octahedron in 3D space based on just two parameters:

- Point 1 - The top most point of the Octahedron (XYZ point in 3D space)
- Point 2 - The bottom most point of the Octahedron (XYZ point in 3D space)

See below

[image: Octahedron with Point1 (top most XYZ) and Point 2 (bottom most XYZ)]

As you can see from the picture above, I also need the shape to be "skewed", so that the top half (side closed to point 1), takes up 85% of the total height between point 1 and 2 (so the shape is not symmetrical).

[image: Length calculate using vector]

I can easily calculate this taking the length of the vector result from (point1 - point2).

I also need the shape to respect if Point 1 is passed in below point 2 (when point 2's Y co-ordinate is greater than point 1's, see below):

[image: Needs to have the smaller portion at the top when point 2 lives in a larger Y co-ordinate]

How do I calculate this if all that is known is the two points?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your conditions don't uniquely specify an octahedron, since (i) your desired shape can be rotated about the axis through Point 1 and Point 2, and (ii) the three axes do not appear to have the same length. Do you want the two axes through the remaining vertices to be parallel to the $X$- and $Z$-coordinate axes, and how do you want those two axis lengths to be determined?

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe this isn't the shape I am looking for then... do you know one that fits this description? :-s

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_1$ be the topmost point, $P_2$ the bottom-most point.
Let $v,w$ be  a unit vectors such that ${P_1P_2},v,w$ are orthogonal.
Let $r>0$ be arbitrary. (There is arbitrariness in the choice of $v,w$ and $r$, which shows thatyour shape is underspecified; I assume you want to let $r$ a constant multiple of $|P_1P_2|$).
Then the points $P_1$, $P_2$, $0.85P_1+0.15P_2+rv$, $0.85P_1+0.15P_2+rw$, $0.85P_1+0.15P_2-rv$, $0.85P_1+0.15P_2-rw$ make up the vertices of a skew octahedron as you describe.

Comment: Hi Hagen, thank you for getting back to me!  I wouldn't say I fully understand the answer (I don't doubt that your correct, I just need it in the simplest terms possible).  Can you write the formula in a step by step fashion?  I intend to convert this theory into c# code.  There are 8 triangles that make up the shape, can you specify how to work out the three points of each triangle?